# Nodejs Express Forward Route Caught Errors To Middleware

Tags: node.js, error-handling

I am trying to understand how to forward errors that occur in routes in a nodejs express application back to the error handler without throwing the error.

Basically I have my middleware setup like this:

```
const allowedMethods = ['GET', 'POST'];

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (!allowedMethods.includes(req.method))
        return res.sendStatus(405);
});

let paymentRoutes = require('./routes/payment');
app.use('/payment', paymentRoutes);

let notificationRoute = require('./routes/notifications');
app.use('/notifications', notificationRoute);

let customerRoutes = require('./routes/customer');
app.use('/customer', customerRoutes);

let subscriptionRoutes = require('./routes/subscription');
app.use('/subscription', subscriptionRoutes);


app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    console.log("error occured!");
    console.log(err);
    if (err) {
        console.log("Throwing an error!");
        next(err);
    } else {
        console.log("no error...")
    }
});

app.use(function logErrors (err, req, res, next) {
    winston.error(err);
    next(err);
});

app.use(function sendMailToAdmin(err, req, res, next) {
    //sendmailtoadmin
});
```

And it is working whenever I throw an error in one of my routes. Currently I am handling errors like this in my routes though.

```
router.get('/:id/has-premium', (req, res) => {
    //throwing a test error
    throw new Error;
    const userId = req.params.id;
    customer.hasActivePremium(userId)
        .then(activePremium => {
            res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({"success": true, "premium": activePremium}));
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(err.httpCode).send(JSON.stringify({"success": false, "error": err.description}));
        })
});
```

**My question is** how would I "call" my middleware error handler with the error I caught when I caught the promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use next in the route signature like

```
router.get('/:id/has-premium', (req, res,next) => {
//throwing a test error
throw new Error; // you can call next() here
const userId = req.params.id;
customer.hasActivePremium(userId)
    .then(activePremium => {
        res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({"success": true, "premium": activePremium}));
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(err.httpCode).send(JSON.stringify({"success": false, "error": err.description}));
    })
```

});

and then call `next(err)` instead of `res.status(err.httpCode).send(JSON.stringify({"success": false, "error": err.description}));`